# undefined reference to `sincos' during installation from source code

Tags: linux, gcc, cmake, makefile, build

I am encountering the following issue while attempting to install CGNS from the source code.

```
make[2]: Leaving directory '/oa/apps/CGNS-4.4.0/src/cgnstools/cgnscalc'
----- utilities -----
make[2]: Entering directory '/oa/apps/CGNS-4.4.0/src/cgnstools/utilities'
gcc -g -O2  -I../common -I/oa/apps/CGNS-4.4.0/src -c plot3d_to_cgns.c
gcc -g -O2  -I../common -I/oa/apps/CGNS-4.4.0/src -c cgnsutil.c
gcc -g -O2  -I../common -I/oa/apps/CGNS-4.4.0/src -c binaryio.c
gcc -g -O2  -I../common -I/oa/apps/CGNS-4.4.0/src -o getargs.o -c ../common/getargs.c
gcc  -o plot3d_to_cgns plot3d_to_cgns.o cgnsutil.o \
binaryio.o getargs.o /oa/apps/CGNS-4.4.0/src/lib/libcgns.a      
/usr/bin/ld: cgnsutil.o: in function `read_zone_grid':
/oa/apps/CGNS-4.4.0/src/cgnstools/utilities/cgnsutil.c:848: undefined reference to `sincos'
/usr/bin/ld: /oa/apps/CGNS-4.4.0/src/cgnstools/utilities/cgnsutil.c:858: undefined reference to `sincos'
/usr/bin/ld: /oa/apps/CGNS-4.4.0/src/cgnstools/utilities/cgnsutil.c:859: undefined reference to `sincos'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile.unix:73: plot3d_to_cgns] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/oa/apps/CGNS-4.4.0/src/cgnstools/utilities'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:70: prog-utilities] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/oa/apps/CGNS-4.4.0/src/cgnstools'
make: *** [Makefile:69: cgnstools] Error 2
```

How can I resolved this error?

Comment: The error is about missing of linkage with `m` library. And it is clear from the `gcc` command line that the parameter `-lm` is actually missed. However, the project's [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/CGNS/CGNS/blob/v4.4.0/src/cgnstools/utilities/CMakeLists.txt#L31) emits linkage with `m` library on non-Windows platforms. Probably, there is something specific about your environment, and it is not pure Linux?

Comment: BTW, according to the path in the last "Leaving directory" - `/oa/apps/CGNS-4.4.0/src/cgnstools` - you are running `make` (and, most likely `ccmake`) from the `/oa/apps/CGNS-4.4.0/src` directory, which `src/` **subdirectory** in the project tree. Instead, you should run `ccmake` from the **project's top directory**, `/oa/apps/CGNS-4.4.0`. (And CMake should emit a warning about wrong usage.)

Comment: Thank you @Tsyvarev, following command solved the issue. 
`export LIBS=-lm`